# Version of Ping that outputs returned Payload?

Tags: ping

Is there a version of Ping that has a command line option that outputs the payload returned?
If so, can you please point me to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[hping](http://www.hping.org/) can dump the received packet. Try `hping -1 -J localhost` which will dump the reply's printable characters.

Comment: I couldn't use this one but this is an interesting answer.  So, I flagged it as the answer.